# Token transfer is not working

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethereum-wallet-dapp, ico, airdrop

I am trying to transfer a token from a token contract. the control reaches till the point where I have the transfer statement later it fails. I do not understand why it is failing. I made sure the account in which I have logged in have sufficient tokens. Could you please assist me to correct the code ?

[image]

[image]

**Code**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.24;

/**
 * @title Ownable
 * @dev The Ownable contract has an owner address, and provides basic authorization control 
 * functions, this simplifies the implementation of "user permissions". 
 */
contract Ownable {
  address public owner;


  /** 
   * @dev The Ownable constructor sets the original `owner` of the contract to the sender
   * account.
   */
  constructor() public {
    owner = 0xca35b7d915458ef540ade6068dfe2f44e8fa733c;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Throws if called by any account other than the owner. 
   */
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    if (msg.sender != owner) {
      throw;
    }
    _;
  }


  /**
   * @dev Allows the current owner to transfer control of the contract to a newOwner.
   * @param newOwner The address to transfer ownership to. 
   */
  function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
    if (newOwner != address(0)) {
      owner = newOwner;
    }
  }

}

contract Token{
  function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns (bool);
}

contract Airdrop1 is Ownable {

    function multisend(address _tokenAddr, address[] _to, uint256[] _value) public
    returns (bool _success) {
        assert(_to.length == _value.length);
        assert(_to.length <= 150);
        // loop through to addresses and send value
        for (uint8 i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                assert((Token(_tokenAddr).transfer(_to[i], _value[i])) == true);
            }
            return true;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The amount of tokens that the account that calls `multisend` has does not matter. What matters is the amount of tokens that the `Airdrop1` contract has, because it tries to transfer tokens. Are you sure it has enough?

An unrelated suggestion: You should probably use `uint256` in your `for` loop instead of `uint8`. Smaller integers can sometimes cost more gas. Also, `uint8` overflows very quickly when you reach `255`.

Comment: You are the man !.  Thanks for making me understand this concept !